# Creating a PHP variable using user input preferably a form

Tags: php

can you declare a php variable using a text input

example:
I want a variable whose name is v1 and its value is 1.
I will first input the name of the variable then set the value of it...

can it be done using php?

Comment: You can't do it using php only without refreshing your page. I'd recommend you to try it with javascript.

Comment: @AlonEitan yes i am also using html i forgot to add that sorry

Comment: @kevinniel thanks for the feedback im looking into it now

Comment: @kevinniel That is not true, actually. You can very well create CLI applications in php, requesting user input from the command line. PHP is _typically_ used in a web environment. But that does not mean you have to...

Comment: `I will first input the name of the variable then set the value of it...` you can't do it without reloading the page... that's what i said... i didn't said it wasn't possible...

Comment: @kevinniel That is not the point and also it is not true. The OP asked if a variable can be created in php using a dynamic variable name. You are making a whole set of assumptions. Why? See my answer below (I extended it for _you_). There is no "page" reloaded... You need to learn to answer to the actual question. Not to what you yourself assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php allows to use a notation like `$$varname` to achieve "dynamic variable names".

So you can do something like that:

```
<?php
$varname = $_POST['varname'];
$$varname = $_POST['value'];
```

However be careful, such stuff opens a whole range of security issues...

It is unclear what you actually want to do... If that is a web form you have in mind or a command line application. Here is a simple example demonstrating above principle:

```
<?php
$varname = readline("enter a variable name: ");
$value = readline("enter a variable value: ");
$$varname = $value;
echo sprintf("variable '%s' now has value '%s'\n", $varname, $$varname);
```

If you execute that and enter the name "abc" and the value "123" the obvious output is:

```
arkascha ~/Test$ php ./test.php
enter a variable name: abc
enter a variable value: 123
variable 'abc' now has value '123'
arkascha ~/Test$
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback and providing me an idea it really helps me

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple method to obtain php variables from a form submission would be to use `extract`

> **extract** — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

[More information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>PHP Variables from form submission</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            username <input type='text' name='username' />
            password <input type='password' name='password' />
            email <input type='email' name='email' />
            number <input type='number' name='number' />
            radio
            <radiogroup>
                <input type='radio' name='rad' value='1' />
                <input type='radio' name='rad' value='2' />
                <input type='radio' name='rad' value='3' />
            </radiogroup>
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                extract( $_POST );

                echo $username, $password, $email, $number, $rad;
            }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```